# \nameref and xifthen's \isempty do not work properly

Tags: cross-referencing, conditionals, nameref, xifthen

So, I made a macros `\fullref` and combined it with `\ifthenelse` to remove `[]` if no content were printed. But when, for example, theorem has no name, `\nameref` prints nothing but `xifthen`'s `\isempty` do not return true. What is happening?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english, ukrainian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


\usepackage{xifthen}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\declaretheoremstyle[
notefont=\normalfont\sffamily, notebraces={}{},
headfont=\bfseries\itshape,
bodyfont=\normalfont\itshape,
headformat=\NAME\ \NUMBER \NOTE,
headpunct=\sffamily.\\,
spaceabove=2mm, spacebelow=2mm,
postheadspace=0mm, headindent=3mm,
]{thmstyle}
\declaretheorem[style=thmstyle, numberwithin=section, name=Theorem]{thm}


\usepackage[]{hyperref}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefname{thm}{thm.}{thms.}

\newcommand{\fullref}[1]{
    (See. \hyperref[#1]{
        \namecref{#1}\ \labelcref*{#1}\ 
        \ifthenelse{\isempty{\nameref*{#1}}}{}{{\sffamily[}\nameref*{#1}{\sffamily]}}, \cpageref{#1}})
}

\begin{document}
    \section{Theorems Section}
    \begin{thm}[Theorem with name]
        Theorem with name
        \label{thm:thm}
    \end{thm}
    \begin{thm}
        Theorem without name
        \label{thm:noname}
    \end{thm}
    
    \begin{gather}
        x^2+4=0,\ x \in \emptyset.\label{eq:shit}   
    \end{gather}

    \section{fullref calls}
    \fullref{thm:thm}\\
    \fullref{eq:shit}\\
    \fullref{thm:noname}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The test `\isempty{\nameref*{#1}}` will always return false.

You need to go deeper. The name is the third braced object (out of five) in a `\newlabel` and you have to test that one.

Thanks to Ulrike Fischer for pointing to `\getrefbykeydefault`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english, ukrainian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}
%\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\declaretheoremstyle[
  notefont=\normalfont\sffamily, notebraces={}{},
  headfont=\bfseries\itshape,
  bodyfont=\normalfont\itshape,
  headformat=\NAME\ \NUMBER \NOTE,
  headpunct=\sffamily.\\,
  spaceabove=2mm, spacebelow=2mm,
  postheadspace=0mm, headindent=3mm,
]{thmstyle}
\declaretheorem[
  style=thmstyle,
  numberwithin=section,
  name=Theorem
]{thm}


\crefname{thm}{thm.}{thms.}

\makeatletter
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\fullref}[1]{%
  (See %
  \hyperref[#1]{%
    \namecref{#1} %
    \labelcref*{#1}, %
    \protected@edef\@temp{\getrefbykeydefault{#1}{name}{}}%
    \if\relax\detokenize\expandafter{\@temp}\relax\else\textsf{[}\nameref*{#1}\textsf{]}, \fi
    \cpageref{#1}%
  }%
  )%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    \section{Theorems Section}
    \begin{thm}[Theorem with name]
        Theorem with name
        \label{thm:thm}
    \end{thm}
    \begin{thm}
        Theorem without name
        \label{thm:noname}
    \end{thm}
    
    \begin{gather}
        x^2+4=0,\ x \in \emptyset.\label{eq:shit}   
    \end{gather}

    \section{fullref calls}
    \fullref{thm:thm}\\
    \fullref{eq:shit}\\
    \fullref{thm:noname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would use `\equal{\getrefbykeydefault{#1}{name}{}}{}`  as test.

Comment: Thank you! I am got what I wanted. But I am curious about that commands that contain `@` and other stuff like that. Is that some core latex syntax or what? Where I can read about it more? (Maybe there is something can be accessed with`texdoc` from my disk already about this stuff?)

Comment: @VladyslavRehan They're used in order to minimize conflicts with user macros.